# Java Spring : How to declare maven dependency to gradle

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I am new to Java Spring. I am following a tutorial regarding Mock FTP server( https://www.baeldung.com/java-ftp-client )

This demo has a Maven dependency. However, how can I build it using gradle ?(http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: As Himesh said, a quick Google search would have helped you. 

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockftpserver/MockFtpServer/2.7.1#gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply search the dependency on google or go to
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockftpserver/MockFtpServer/2.7.1
and click under *gradle* tab.

Meanwhile, to answer your question, this should work

```
testCompile group: 'org.mockftpserver', name: 'MockFtpServer', version: '2.7.1'
```